# shape '[700, -1]' is invalid for input of size 4020

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, tensor

I am getting an error and cannot figure out how to solve it. My experience with pytorch is a contributing factor. I am working on google colaboratory currently, and working ove r an LNP pproject but I just got stuck when it came to actually creating a model because of this error.

```
# STEP 3.3

# Create an instance of the model
import numpy as np
import time
model = EncoderDecoder().float().to(device)
prev_valid_loss = 1e100
# This scales the size of each step of backpropagation
learning_rate = 20
# This value should match the batch_size used earlier for splitting up the data
batch_size = 20

num_epochs = 10                # CHANGEME
timing = time.time()
for epoch in range(num_epochs):

  # Set the model to training mode and iterate through the dataset
  model.train()
  hidden = None
  train_loss = 0
  start_time = time.time()
  for i in range(0, train.size(0) - 1, seq_len):
    # Get the next training batch
    data, targets = get_batch(train, i, seq_len)
  
  # Run the model and perform backpropagation
    loss, hidden = training(model, data, targets, learning_rate, hidden)
    train_loss += loss

  # Evaluate how well the model predicts unseen validation data
  valid_loss = evaluation(model)

  # Check if the model's ability to generalize has gotten worse.
  # If so, slow the learning rate (shrink the step size)
  if valid_loss > prev_valid_loss:
    learning_rate /= 4.0

  # Print the training and validation performance
  train_loss /= (train.size(0)/seq_len)
  finish_time = time.time()
  print("Epoch {:2} took {:3.2f}s with train perplexity: {:7.2f}"\
        " and validation: {:7.2f}".format(epoch, finish_time - start_time, 
                                          np.exp(train_loss), 
                                          np.exp(valid_loss)))
  
  prev_valid_loss = valid_loss

total_time = (time.time() - timing)/60
print("Completed {} epochs in {:5.3f} minutes".format(num_epochs, total_time))
```

I tried to experiment around and search on existing sources but couldn't fix it. I am getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-7552c8b16c44> in <cell line: 15>()
     25 
     26   # Run the model and perform backpropagation
---> 27     loss, hidden = training(model, data, targets, learning_rate, hidden)
     28     train_loss += loss
     29 

<ipython-input-16-2102d1d377c2> in training(model, data, targets, lr, hidden)
      8   # Run the model to see its predictions and hidden states
      9   hidden, prediction_vector = model(data, hidden)
---> 10   prediction_vector = prediction_vector.view(seq_len * batch_size, -1)
     11 
     12   # Compare the model's predictions at each timestep to the original data

RuntimeError: shape '[700, -1]' is invalid for input of size 4020
```

Comment: Also the if I am doing it in another notebook I am getting the error: loss_fn is not defined for some reason which I do not see.

Comment: Welcome to SO, ルdra. Layers in `pytorch` need to have compatible input/output dimensions. For example, a layer "A" with output dimensions 10 x 42 would not be able to fit into a layer "B" if the input has dimensions 11 x 42.